# applying custom function to different experimental conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data similar to below. **ppt** = participant number; **condition** = experimental condition of trial; **difficulty** = difficulty level of trial; **correct** = whether the ppt chose correctly or not (1 = correct, 0 = incorrect); and **key_rt** is participant reaction time when making their choice

```
data <- data.frame(ppt = rep(c(50, 51, 52), each = 20),
                   condition = rep(c("happy", "sad", "neutral"), times = 20), 
                   difficulty = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1)),
                   correct = rep(0:1, times = 15, each = 2), 
                   key_rt = runif(15))
```

I'd like to apply a function to this data. The data I am applying this function to now is slightly more complex because there are different experimental conditions and difficulty levels, so I have used some for loops within my code for which I apply the function to.

```
conds = c("happy", "sad", "neutral")
diffs = c(1, 2, 3)

df <- data %>%
  for (conds in condition) {
    for (diffs in difficulty) { 
      group_by(ppt) %>%
      summarise(Pc = mean(correct),
                VRT = var(key_rt[correct==1]),
                MRT = mean(key_rt[correct==1]),
                out = list(my_fun(Pc, VRT, MRT, n()))) %>%
      unnest_wider(out) 
  }
}
```

However, the df does not store within the global environment, and there is no error message, so I'm struggling to figure out where I have gone wrong here. I want to apply the function separately to the experimental conditions and difficulty levels for each participant.

The desired outcome would look like below (and columns for Ter but there was no space to add them here):

| v_1_happy | v_2_happy | v_3_happy | a_1_sad | a_2_sad | a_3_sad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.80 | 2.00 | 2.55 | 1.57 | 1.99 | 2.01 |

Comment: Could you explain wath is `key_resp_3.rt`?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, this was a typo - now changed to 'key_rt' which is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `lapply` and `split` functions. First, you must create a function make the job for every subset (every condition and difficulty combinations). Then apply the function for every subset with `lapply`. `split` will help you to create the subsets. Try this:

```
my_fun <- function(data){
      data %>%
            group_by(ppt) %>%
            summarise(Pc = mean(correct),
                      VRT = var(key_rt[correct==1]),
                      MRT = mean(key_rt[correct==1]),
                      out = list(EZ(Pc, VRT, MRT, n()))) %>%
            unnest_wider(out) 
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lapply(split(data,paste(data$condition,data$difficulty)),my_fun)
```

The Output is a list of results by ppt for every subset.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I converted the output of lists into a data frame by putting "df <- as.data.frame(lapply(split(data, paste(data$condition, data$difficulty)), my_fun))" which allowed me to clean it up a bit as there were some duplicate columns, such as ppt number

Comment: You are welcome, but take care `as.data.frame` only takes the first object in the list and discard the others. It's better to use `bind_rows()` function like this: `bind_rows(lapply(split(data, paste(data$condition, data$difficulty)), my_fun))`.